# A (classical) bound on the jumps of a cadlag function: $\left|\Delta f(t)\right|\leq 2\,\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\left|f(s)\right|$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, absolute-value, supremum-and-infimum

For a [càdlàg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g) function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ I need to prove the following intuitive bound

$$
\left|\Delta f(t)\right|=\left|f(t)-f(t-)\right|\leq 2\,\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\left|f(s)\right|
$$

The idea is that

$$
\left|\Delta f(t)\right|\leq \left|f(t)\right|+\left|f(t-)\right|\leq \sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\left|f(s)\right|+\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\left|f(s-)\right|
$$

But I miss to prove that $$\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\left|f(s-)\right|=\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\left|f(s)\right|$$

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0 \le \tau < t$ is
$$
\begin{align}
 |f(t-)| &\le |f(t-) - f(\tau)| + |f(\tau)| \\
&\le \underbrace{|f(t-) - f(\tau)|}_{\to 0 \text{ for } \tau \nearrow t } + \sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|f(s)|
\end{align}
$$
so that
$$
|f(t-)| \le \sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|f(s)| \, .
$$
Also, obviously,
$$
|f(t)| \le \sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|f(s)| \, ,
$$
and therefore
$$
 |\Delta f(t)| \le |f(t)| + |f(t-)| \le 2 \sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|f(s)| \, .
$$

*Remark:* We used only the existence of the left limit, not the right continuity.

Answer (score -1):

For cadlag (right-continuous with left limits) $f$, you can show:

$$|Δf(t)| = |f(t) - f(t-)| ≤ 2\sup_{ 0≤s≤t} |f(s)|$$

**Proof:**

Since $f$ is cadlag, $f(t-) = f(t)$ for all $t$.
So
$$
\begin{split}\sup_{0≤s≤t} |f(s-)| = \sup_{0≤s≤t} |f(s)|&\qquad \text{(swap suprema)}\\
|Δf(t)| ≤ |f(t)| + |f(t-)| ≤ 2 \sup_{0≤s≤t} |f(s)|&\qquad\text{(use step 2)}
\end{split}$$

The key point is that for cadlag functions, the left and right limits agree at each point, so you can swap the two suprema. The end result is that the difference between left/right limits is bounded by twice the maximum value on the given subinterval.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE :) First, note that contributors are expected to use MathJax (Latex) for the maths parts in posts, so please try to do that. Secondly, it's not true that $f(t-) = f(t)$ for cadlag functions (which is more or less the point of those functions). This would be true for continuous functions

Comment: okay, my statement was too strong. For cadlag functions, f(t-) and f(t) agree at every point t, but they are not equal as functions. f(t-) represents the left limit of f at t, while f(t) represents the value of f at t. So they agree at every point, but f(t-) is a function that takes on the left limits, while f(t) takes on the values.

Yes, that for continuous functions, f(t-) = f(t) would hold as an equality of functions, not just of values. But for cadlag functions, the left and right limits/values agree at each point, but f(t-) and f(t) are not equal functions. I appreciate the correction.

Comment: I've done you the favour of formatting your work with MathJax, however, in the future, you're going to want to so this yourself. Here are some resources on how to write mathematics on this site; see [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Good luck, and welcome to MSE.

Comment: @AnonImus I'm not sure I exactly understand what you mean, but it's not the case that $f(t-)$ and $f(t)$ agree. Take e.g. $f = 1_{[0, \infty)}$. Then $f$ is cadlag, $f(0)=1$ and $f(0-)=0$.